# The shortest combination of paths that starts and ends with a single node and covers all points in an undirected graph

Tags: ruby, algorithm, graph, combinations, shortest-path

I need an `algorithm(k, s)` where

- `k` is the number of paths
- `s` is the starting and ending node

and given `n` number of nodes in an undirected graph in which all nodes are linked to each other, returns `k` paths to traverse all nodes of which the sum of distances covered by the `k` paths is the shortest.

E.g. Given `n` = `10`, `algorithm(2,5)` might give me an array of two arrays such that the sum of the distances covered by the two paths are the shortest and that all nodes are traversed.

```
[[5,1,2,3,10,5],[5,4,6,7,8,9,5]]
```

Djikstra's algorithm finds the shortest path from one node to another, but not the shortest combination of `k` paths.

Yen's algorithm finds `k` number of shortest paths from one node to another, but not the shortest combination of `k` paths.

What algorithm can help me find the shortest combination of `k` paths that starts and end with node `s` such that all `n` nodes are covered?

Comment: I think that we can do that using DFS, by computing the length of the path every time. If we reach k, we verify if the next node is the starting node or no, True if it's the case, False if not. We loop in all the possibilities, as we will have different possibilities every-time we choose different node after the starting node (I assume that's unweighted graph).

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing above, is the classical Traveling Sales Man problem, many optimization techniques. One such is [Ant Colony Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_colony_optimization_algorithms).

There are many libraries that implement ACO, you could find one for Ruby, as it stands, there are no easy solutions to [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) with classical (mathematical) approach.